# Pandas+Numpy: filtering DF columns by numerical dtype gives unexpected behavior

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following table (sample to ease whoever wants to try):

> serial;spectra;name;UKST;ra;dec;ra2000;dec2000;BJG;BJSEL;BJG_OLD;BJSELOLD;GALEXT;SB_BJ;SR_R;z;z_helio;obsrun;quality;abemma;Z_ABS;KBESTR;R_CRCOR;Z_EMI;NMBEST;SNR;ETA_TYPE
>   1;2;TGS436Z001;349;00:11:55.72;-32:32:55.2;00:14:27.05;-32:16:14.6;19.424;19.362;19.430;19.390;0.062;19.368;18.286;0.2981;0.2981;01SEP;4;1;0.2981;5;4.5700;0.2984;1;3.8;-99.90000
>   2;1;TGS496Z001;349;00:11:59.29;-33:14:41.3;00:14:30.55;-32:58:00.7;18.842;18.789;18.870;18.840;0.053;18.688;17.291;0.1229;0.1228;01OCT;5;1;0.1229;1;14.3800;-9.9990;0;47.6;-2.58920
>   3;1;TGS435Z001;349;00:11:49.37;-32:39:57.4;00:14:20.71;-32:23:16.8;18.320;18.265;18.350;18.310;0.055;18.336;17.138;0.1038;0.1038;01SEP;4;1;0.1038;1;9.3800;0.1032;1;28.4;-2.46500

```
sidenote:
You should have a pandas dataframe from the above '''data-sample''' as follows:
>>> import StringIO
>>> _tmp = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> _tmp.write('''data-sample''')
>>> _tmp.seek(0)
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.read_csv(_tmp,delimiter=';')
```

The correspoding `df` we get has the following `dtypes` information:

```
>>> df.dtypes
serial        int64
spectra       int64
name         object
UKST          int64
ra           object
dec          object
ra2000       object
dec2000      object
BJG         float64
BJSEL       float64
BJG_OLD     float64
BJSELOLD    float64
GALEXT      float64
SB_BJ       float64
SR_R        float64
z           float64
z_helio     float64
obsrun       object
quality       int64
abemma        int64
Z_ABS       float64
KBESTR        int64
R_CRCOR     float64
Z_EMI       float64
NMBEST        int64
SNR         float64
ETA_TYPE    float64
dtype: object
```

All I wanna do is simply filter the column names given their data types; in particular, I want to keep the numeric columns. So, all I thought I should do was to check whether their `dtype` was a `numpy.number`,

```
>>> filter(lambda c:df[c].dtypes == numpy.number,df.columns)
['BJG',
'BJSEL',
'BJG_OLD',
'BJSELOLD',
'GALEXT',
'SB_BJ',
'SR_R',
'z',
'z_helio',
'Z_ABS',
'R_CRCOR',
'Z_EMI',
'SNR',
'ETA_TYPE']
```

but as we can see all I get are the `>float` columns, *the `>int` ones are left behind*.

I **do** get the result I want by doing:

```
>>> filter(lambda c:df[c].dtypes == numpy.floating or df[c].dtypes == numpy.integer, df.columns)
['serial',
'spectra',
'UKST',
'BJG',
'BJSEL',
'BJG_OLD',
'BJSELOLD',
'GALEXT',
'SB_BJ',
'SR_R',
'z',
'z_helio',
'quality',
'abemma',
'Z_ABS',
'KBESTR',
'R_CRCOR',
'Z_EMI',
'NMBEST',
'SNR',
'ETA_TYPE']
```

(Obs: `numpy.floating` or `numpy.number` give same result at the line above.)

The question here is: isn't `numpy.number` expected to "represent" any numerical type in numpy (int,float,complex,etc)? 
After reading the corresponding classes hierarchy at `numpy.core.numerictypes` help pages, the above presented behavior is unexpected to me...
Does anybody has a comment on that? Am I missing something?

Cheers.

Comment: does `df.select_dtypes([np.number])` work?

Comment: @EdChum: It does. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and pass `np.number` in a list object:

```
In [160]:
df.select_dtypes([np.number]).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 21 columns):
serial      3 non-null int64
spectra     3 non-null int64
UKST        3 non-null int64
BJG         3 non-null float64
BJSEL       3 non-null float64
BJG_OLD     3 non-null float64
BJSELOLD    3 non-null float64
GALEXT      3 non-null float64
SB_BJ       3 non-null float64
SR_R        3 non-null float64
z           3 non-null float64
z_helio     3 non-null float64
quality     3 non-null int64
abemma      3 non-null int64
Z_ABS       3 non-null float64
KBESTR      3 non-null int64
R_CRCOR     3 non-null float64
Z_EMI       3 non-null float64
NMBEST      3 non-null int64
SNR         3 non-null float64
ETA_TYPE    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(14), int64(7)
memory usage: 528.0 bytes
```